# Hot to combine two custom components values into one with react-hook-forms

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form with a two separate custom components - 1 for datepick and 1 for timepick. Each of these fields returns **Date** type value. I'm using `react-hook-form` for the form management. My question is how to combine the values from these two components and send one combined value to the server using the aforementioned library, using 1 single controller? Is it even possible? If not what is the best tactic to do this? Here's  a simplification of what it looks like:

```
function DateTime() {
  const {
    field: { onChange },
  } = useController({
    name: 'dateTimeFrom',
  })

  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
      />

      <TimePicker
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using one single component for both of them? Is there any reasoning behind this? Also I believe `useController` can be used only for one input filed. Can you provide codesandbox if possible?

Comment: Because we already have a datepicker package which doesn't support time picking implemented into the project and I was tasked to create a separate timepicker component. Now there's a form which has two separate datepicker and timepicker fields, but the requirement is to send just 1 value to to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using custom useStateCallback hook, so I would be able to `setDateTime` first, then to run the `onChange` with the transform `getDateTime()` function. I'd just want to know if this is a good practise in any way?

```
function useStateCallback(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const cbRef = useRef(null);

  const setStateCallback = useCallback((state, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb;
    setState(state);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state);
      cbRef.current = null;    }
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setStateCallback];
}
```

```
import useStateCallback from './useStateCallback'

function DateTime() {
  const {
    field: { onChange },
  } = useController({
    name: 'dateTimeFrom',
  })

  const getDateTime = ({ date, time }: any) =>
    `${format(new Date(date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')} ${format(new Date(time), 'HH:mm')}`

  const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useStateCallback({ date: null, time: null })

  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={(value) => {
          setDateTime({ ...dateTime, date: value }, newDateTime =>
            onChange(getDateTime(newDateTime))
          )
        }}
      />

      <TimePicker
        onChange={(time) => {
          setDateTime({ ...dateTime, time: time }, newDateTime =>
            onChange(getDateTime(newDateTime))
          )
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```